# Node.js For-Loop and Readline Function Calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to input a series of test scores and determine their average in JavaScript, and I figured I'd try out Node.js. The function readTestScores() utilizes readline's question() method -- from Node.js's [Readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_question_query_callback) module to obtain a final exam score with a nested for-loop on the inside, with its own call to question() to obtain seven test scores. See below (yes, I know, my code looks messy):

```
function readTestScores() {
    var score = 0;

    rl.question('Enter exam score:', (examScore) => {
        console.log("Enter test scores: ");
        for (var i=0; i < 7; i++) {
            rl.question('', (score) => {
            test_avg += score;
            });
        }
        rl.close();
    });
    test_avg /= 7;
}
```

When I run my code, when execution gets to the for-loop it skips all of the question() calls until the very end, and I can only input one value before the program terminates. Is there a way I can correct this?

Edit: Here's the code I used to create the readline interface:

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
```

Comment: Looks like a timing issue with looping and when the callback function is actually being executed.

Comment: i isn't used inside the loop, so I don't get why it would be a closure issue. @Charybdis can you show the question method? There's probably an easier way to do this, but then we must know what the rl object and its methods do.

Comment: Ah, it's part of Node.js's [Readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_question_query_callback) module. The question() method displays a query argument, awaits user input then executes a callback function with the input as its first argument.

Comment: @Shilly (Sorry, not sure if you get notifications on comments)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to calculate an average using Readline, based on the tiny cli tutorial:

```
'use strict';

var aiScores = [];
var iAverage;

function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.setPrompt('Enter exam score > ');
rl.prompt();

rl.on('line', (line) => {
  console.log(line);
  if (Number.isInteger(parseFloat(line))) {
      aiScores.push(parseFloat(line));
      console.log(aiScores);
      console.log(parseFloat(line));
      iAverage = (aiScores.reduce(add, 0)/aiScores.length);
      console.log('Current average = ' + iAverage);
  } else {
      switch(line.trim()) {
        case 'hello':
          console.log('world!');
        case 'close':
          rl.close();
          break;
        default:
          console.log(`Say what? I might have heard '${line.trim()}'`);
          break;
      }
  }
  rl.prompt();
}).on('close', () => {
  console.log('Have a great day!');
  process.exit(0);
});
```